# How to get the id in the URI when using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working on a CodeIgniter project and trying to get the id of this URI:

> `http://example.com/myDomain/index.php/public/calendar/gestionEvent?id=c2pnumqnqr0dg9tgmaklho5280@google.com`

I want the controller to delete or update the event using this ID.

I tried `$this->uri->segment(4)`but it doesn't seem to work and doesn't show anything.

Comment: Is the expected id `c2pnumqnqr0dg9tgmaklho5280@google.com`?

Comment: @ Wesley Murch , without @google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cotroller

```
$id = $this->input->get('id');

$data['id'] = $id ;
```

you can not use uri segment here

```
ex:-http://example.com/index.php/news/local/metro/crime_is_up
```

here you can use uri segments

```
The segment numbers would be this:

1.news
2.local
3.metro
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

```
UPDATE
```

if you want to get only the id with out `@google.com` you can simply use `explode()`

```
$id_string = $this->input->get('id');

$id_string_exp = explode("@", $id_string);

$id = $id_string_exp[0];
```

Comment: @ Kanishka Panamaldeniya , thank you for your answer. Actually I would like to have only the id without @google.com. Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$id = $this->input->get_post('id');
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Then use

```
$id = $this->input->get('id');

$this->uri->segment(4) will work only if the url is in the form of segments like
http://example.com/myDomain/index.php/public/calendar/gestionEvent/c2pnumqnqr0dg9tgmaklho5280@google.com
```

Then you will get id using "URI segments".Thanku.i hope this helps you friend